# How do I recover password saved in service?

Tags: windows-7, passwords, windows-services

I have a genomics analysis machine based on Windows 7 (MiSeq from Illumina). Somebody set up a SMB share to that machine with username and password (e.g. .\sbsuser) at least two years ago, but seems nobody recorded the password. According to the menu, it must get specified on Windows 7 service (Start -> service.msc -> MiSeq -> Use different credential) in order to work.

Since the worker who originally set this up is gone, is it possible to retrieve the password over there? Reset the password would be the last and least preferred option since already other machines depend on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it for authenticating other machines to the SMB share on the machine the service runs or what? The other machines only need to access the SMB share with that credential? You could technically create an additional account and grant it appropriate permissions to the SMB share and document that detail and use it moving forward on machines you need to change or whatever and the ones using the existing credential can continue to use whatever they are using. Does the service run on every machine or just the one with the SMB share or what?

Comment: If you cannot do something simple as that, then you will likely need to go with some hacking techniques potentially but read over https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/178347/recover-the-password-of-a-windows-service-user-login-account for a starting point and see if you can figure it out. Otherwise you will likely need to get a copy of the SAM file and get the hash from it and then run that hash thru some rainbow tables to see if someone has already deciphered that hash to the clear text. You'll maybe need to resort to brute force guessing otherwise.

Comment: It might be just easier to change the user's password then update the stored password.  You can always create a new user, and update any current connected application or service to use that new user, and keep the original user.